How do I add 'week of year' and 'day of year' columns to a python datatable?
There is currently (version 1.1.0) no python datatable.time.week() or datatable.time.day_of_year() functions.
Here is some example data:
from datetime import date
import datatable as dt


DT = dt.Frame({"Date": ["2021-05-24", "2021-06-26", "2021-07-27"]}, stype='date32')

datatable.time documentation

I'm not interested in using pandas, polars, vaex or other related packages.  The question is solely concerned with python datatable and date processing.

One solution, is to convert the datatable Date column to a list and process it with appropriate functions from the datetime library.
Using the given example data:
from datetime import date
import datatable as dt
    
    
DT = dt.Frame({"Date": ["2021-05-24", "2021-06-26", "2021-07-27"]}, stype='date32')

weeks_list = [_date.isocalendar().week for _date in DT["Date"].to_list()[0]]
DT[:, "week"] = dt.Frame(weeks_list)

doy_list = [_date.timetuple().tm_yday for _date in DT["Date"].to_list()[0]]
DT[:, "day_of_year"] = dt.Frame(doy_list)

DT

Which should give the following output:
    Date       week day_of_year
    ▪▪▪▪       ▪▪▪▪ ▪▪▪▪
0   2021-05-24  21  144
1   2021-06-26  25  177
2   2021-07-27  30  208
3 rows × 3 columns


I'd be happy to see faster or more py-datatable idiomatic answers.

If you're looking for something more idiomatic then what you're really asking for is enhanced functionality within the non-standard datatable module. In which case you should contact the author(s) of that module. BTW - Don't try unstalling datatable on Mac M* because it's not supported (X86 only)

So far, I've only used python datatable on Google Colab.  Thanks for Mac M* info.  I can see it being a deal-breaker for some.
